# Is there any particular local traditions amongst any Christian denominations in the city of Damascus for celebrating the Conversion of St. Paul?

Tags: tradition, paul-apostle, feasts, local-churches, damascus

Is there any particular local traditions amongst any Christian denominations in the city of [Damascus](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Damascus) for celebrating the Conversion of St. Paul?

The Catholic Church celebrates the Feast of the Conversion of St. Paul on  January 25th each year.

> The conversion of Paul the Apostle (also Pauline conversion, Damascene conversion, Damascus Christophany and The Road to Damascus event), was, according to the New Testament, an event in the life of Paul the Apostle that led him to cease persecuting early Christians and to become a follower of Jesus. It is normally dated to AD 33–36. Since his birth is estimated at 5 AD, he would have been somewhere around the age of 28–31 at his conversion.
>
> The Feast of the Conversion of Saint Paul the Apostle is a feast celebrated during the liturgical year on January 25, recounting the conversion. This feast is celebrated in the Roman Catholic, Anglican and Lutheran churches. This feast is at the conclusion of the Week of Prayer for Christian Unity, an international Christian ecumenical observance that began in 1908, which is an octave (an eight-day observance) spanning from January 18 (observed in Anglican and Lutheran tradition as the Confession of Peter, and in the pre-1961 Roman Catholic Church as the feast of the Chair of Saint Peter at Rome) to January 25. In rural England, the day functioned much like groundhog day does in the modern-day United States. Supposed prophecies ranged from fine days predicting good harvests, to clouds and mists signifying pestilence and war in the coming months. - [Conversion of Paul the Apostle](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conversion_of_Paul_the_Apostle)

**Outside any liturgical celebrations, are there any local traditional ways for commemorating this event by the Christians of Damascus or it’s surrounding areas?**